# Generic class whose parameter extends a nested class

Tags: c#, inner-classes, c#-7.2

This C# doesn't compile:

```
public class IdList<T> where T : IdList<T>.Item {
  List<T> List = new List<T>();

  public T this[int id] {
    get => List[id];
    set { }
  }

  public class Item {
    public int id;
    // Not shown: id used for equality and hash.
  }
}
```

The complaint from the compiler is:

> The type 'IdList' already contains a definition for 'Item'

If I comment out the indexer, it compiles.

How can I get this to compile? Rider doesn't have a fixit.

The unstylish workaround is not to nest the Item class.

IDE is Rider 2018.1.4, Language level 7.2, on macOS.

Comment: Interestingly, rename inner class `Item` to `Foo`...

Comment: Upvote for teaching me about one of dotnet's dirty little secrets!

Comment: I'm intrigued by your use case.  Why would you structure a class like this?  Maybe it's still to early in the morning for me to suss out what you are trying to accomplish.  But, yeah, indexers introduce a magic property named "Item", work around that and you should be golden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: eliminate the name collision by using, for example,
[`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("TheItem")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers)

```
public class IdList<T> where T : IdList<T>.Item {
  List<T> List = new List<T>();

  [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("TheItem")]
  public T this[int id] {
    get => List[id];
    set { }
  }

  public class Item {
    public int id;
    // Not shown: id used for equality and hash.
  }
}
```

The compiler error should be more explicit and say that `Item` is already defined as the default name (which can be overridden) for the indexer, and the IDE should offer this fixit.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that the indexer, when compiled to .NET byte code, becomes a property called "Item". You need to change your type name to something else.

Comment: You might also want to look at [`[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("TheItem")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers)

Comment: In other words: a slight improvement in the error message would have helped.